# How to write or print Array(22,6) to csv file using for loop? with detail explanation

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop, text-files

Excel data in 22 rows and 6 columns, how to write or print them to text (csv) file using for loop, Also please explain.

```
 Sub Simple_Text()
  Dim FName As String
  Dim ArrayRange As Variant
  Dim r As Long, c As Long

  Dim lRow As Long: lRow = _
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSV").Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row - 3
  Dim lCol As Long: lCol = _
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSV").Range("A4").End(xlToRight).Column
      FName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\SajidTest2.csv"

      ReDim ArrayRange(1 To lRow, 1 To lCol)

     'Populate Array range with value in the table from sheet "CSV"
      'row loop
      For r = 1 To lRow
       'column loop
        For c = 1 To lCol
         ArrayRange(r, c) = Cells(r + 3, c).Value
        Next c
        Next r

       'Make Entries in the text CSV file
        Open FName For Output As #1

       'row loop
        For r = 1 To lRow

         Print #1, ArrayRange(r, 1) & "," & ArrayRange(r, 2) & "," & _ 
           ArrayRange(r, 3) & "," & _
        ArrayRange(r, 4) & "," & ArrayRange(r, 5) & "," & ArrayRange(r, 6)

         Next r
            Close #1

          End Sub
```

I want use for loop for both rows and columns data for writing it to the csv file

Comment: Please show us what you have tried after doing your research and explain the problem you had with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Open FName For Output As #1
For r = 1 To lRow
    Dim s As String: s = ""
    For c = 1 To lCol
        s = s & ArrayRange(r, c) & ","
    Next
    Print #1, Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
Next
Close #1
```

for more optimization you can use it without array to save more system resources

```
Open FName For Output As #1
    For r = 1 To lRow
        Dim s As String: s = ""
        For c = 1 To lCol
            s = s & Cells(r + 3, c).Value
        Next c
        Print #1, Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
    Next r
Close #1
```

Comment: I also want to know, I have used arrays for this code, this code can be written without arrays, which one is better...is there anything like code optimization in VBA...what are the best practices to write code....also you have declared variable in between the code...is it a good way of writing the code....

Answer (score 0):

I want to offer a more modern solution in terms of file handling (instead of the legacy `Open` and `Print`). Instead, I am suggesting to use a [**`FileSystemObject`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object), in addition to the [**`Join()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.join?view=netcore-3.1) method to take care of placing the commas in the correct place.

### Prepare

Add a reference to the `Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime`

[image: References]

by selecting it from the (long) list of reference .dll
[image: MSR]

and <kbd>OK</kbd> out of there.

### File Handing Code

First, the driver subroutine that creates the file and saves it. This calls **`ToCSV()`** to generate the csv contents as `String`.

```
Public Sub SaveCsvToFile()
    Dim csv As String, r As Range
    ' Set range of export starting from "A4"
    ' and spanning 22 rows and 6 columns
    Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Resize(22, 6)
    
    ' Call function to convert data in range to csv string
    csv = RangeToCSV(r, formatted:=False)
    
    Dim fso as NewFileSystemObject
    Dim fn As String
    ' Get filename adjecent to workbook
    fn = fso.BuildPath(ThisWorkbook.Path, "SajidTest2.csv")
    ' Or get filename in temp folder
    ' fn = fso.BuildPath(fso.GetSpecialFolder(2), "SajidTest2.csv")
    
    ' Create or open the file and write the csv file
    Dim fs As TextStream
    Set fs = fso.CreateTextFile(fn, True)
    Call fs.Write(csv)
    fs.Close
        
End Sub
```

and now the helper function to generate the csv contents from an Excel range.

```
Public Function RangeToCSV(ByVal r_data As Range, ByVal formatted As Boolean) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim n As Long, m As Long
    
    ' Get the range size (#rows & #columns)
    n = r_data.Rows.Count: m = r_data.Columns.Count
    
    Dim csv As String, csv_row As String
    Dim data() As String
    
    ' Create a working string array to store each
    ' row of the table as comma delimited
    ReDim data(0 To m - 1)
    For i = 1 To n
        ' For each row, go through the columns and
        ' extract the data into the working array
        For j = 1 To m
            If formatted Then
                ' Store actual data
                data(j - 1) = CStr(r_data.Cells(i, j).Value)
            Else
                ' Or to store formatted text
                data(j - 1) = r_data.Cells(i, j).Text
            End If
        Next j
        ' Convert array of strings, into a delimited string
        ' {"A","B","C"} => "A,B,C"
        csv_row = Strings.Join(data, ",")
        
        ' Add row into result and add a new line feed
        csv = csv & csv_row & vbCrLf
    Next i
    RangeToCSV = csv
End Function
```

Comment: Hi John, Thank you, the code is overwhelming as I am still a novice in VBA. I am learning something new. what benefit does the enabling microsoft script runtime does?

Comment: Look carefully at the documentation I linked. It shows you can check if a file exists, extract file, path and extensions, read and write file streams, handle temporary files, get special folders, and everything a modern OS supports.

Comment: What I usually do, is in a module add the line on top `Global fso as NewFileSystemObject` and then I have access to all the file system operations from all my code using the `fso` variable. For example `fso.GetParentFolderName(path)`.